# Having trouble with the one_of feature in Getopt::Long::Descriptive

Tags: perl

When I use the "one_of" special specification in Getopt::Long::Descriptive, I get errors for the options I did **not** put on the command line.  I would like to have Getopt::Long::Descriptive handle the mutually exclusive options for me; but I don't know how to use the specification without generating errors.

If I list the options **without** including them in a one_of specifier, they do work as expected.  However, I can then put multiple options on the command line which should be mutually exclusive.  Perl 5.26.1 and Getopt::Long::Descriptive 0.104 if it helps.

```
use Getopt::Long::Descriptive;

my $usage_desc = "%c %o mailbox|ticket <This script lists or adds stuff>";
my @opt_spec   = (
    [
        "mode" => hidden => {
            one_of => [
                [ 'list|l=s' => 'lists stuff' ],
                [ 'add|a=s' => 'adds stuff' ],
            ]
        }
    ],
    [ 'verbose|v' => 'increase the verbosity level in the log file' ],
    [ 'help'      => 'print usage message and exit', { shortcircuit => 1 } ],
);

my ( $opt, $usage ) = describe_options( $usage_desc, @opt_spec );

print( $usage->text ), exit if $opt->help;

if ( $opt->verbose ) {
    $debug_level++;
    print "option --verbose specified; debug level now at $debug_level\n";
}

if ( $opt->list ) {
    my $argument = $opt->list;
    print "option --list specified, with argument: $argument\n";
}

if ( $opt->add ) {
    my $argument = $opt->add;
    print "option --add specified, with argument: $argument\n";
}

foreach my $argument ( @ARGV ) {
    print "argument '$argument\' supplied (without an option specified)\n";
    handle_search_terms( $argument );
}
```

When I run my script, for example with --list foo, then I get an error

```
"Can't locate object method "add" via package "Getopt::Long::Descriptive::Opts::__OPT__::1" at line 38."
```

If I run it with --add bar, then I get the error "Can't locate object method "list" via package...."

My problem is that I don't know how to structure my code so that the options **not** used don't generate errors.

Comment: You can also do `if ($opt->_specified("list")) {...}`. See [Getopt::Long::Descriptive::Opts](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long::Descriptive) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $opt->mode eq 'list' ) {
    my $argument = $opt->list;
    print "option --list specified, with argument: $argument\n";
}
elsif ( $opt->mode eq 'add' ) {
    my $argument = $opt->add;
    print "option --add specified, with argument: $argument\n";
}
```

And don't forget:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

All of this is [described in the documentation](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long::Descriptive).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm somewhat new to Perl, and don't think I've ever used the elsif construct before.  For what it is worth, I needed to add if( defined $opt->mode ){} as a wrapper around the whole iff .. elseif piece to get the script to handle supplying an argument without an option.